# How to create strategy pattern for a lot of options

Tags: c++, strategy-pattern

Firstly I show some code:

1) In process 1:

```
if (current_job == IT_jobs) // accept;
else if (current_job == art_job) // next check...
```

2) In process 2:

```
if (current_person == asian_group) // ...
else // ...
```

So, there are two different kinds of processes, the different things is that they are for different purposes, but they use the same method, comparing the variables, `IT_jobs` and `asian_group` are variables containing values.

What I want to do is to put these kind of things in a good way, like `if (entry.strategy)`, make them more standardized, and I put these variables in a database, when I need to make a comparison, I read them. Is it possible? How to realize this kind of strategy pattern. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Your question is rather unclear, specifically the "What I want to do" bit. You seem to be asking how you can wrap an already quite general equality test in some confusing and ill-defined object oriented pattern; this is not a useful thing to do. I'm assuming I've misunderstood, so perhaps you could clarify?

Comment: Sorry, because I am working on a very small part for a huge project, the things is like `if (Validator::isVariableIn("APM_TAG")`, I mean this kind of variables `APM_TAG` appear in many places, maybe `BPM_TAG`, `CPM_TAG`....so I want to put these options separately, but I can't rebuild the whole project...Thanks